# Running env bash on Mac Produces a Killed 9 Error

Tags: bash, macos

Whenever I run env bash on a shell or try to run a script that has env bash as its shebang, env always fails with a killed: 9 error. Does anyone know how to fix this? Running env on other interpreters like zsh or python works fine, it's just specifically when I try to run it with bash that I get this error.

Comment: Which copy of bash is first in your `PATH`? That is, what does `command -v bash` (in any POSIX-y shell), or `type bash` (if already in bash) or `which bash` (if in zsh) return? Can you start that executable directly?

Comment: `/bin/bash` should always work since it's provided by Apple themselves, but if there's a different copy of bash earlier in the PATH, then we need to worry about whether it's actually a valid/appropriate binary.

Comment: (context for asking the question: the purpose of `env` is to do a PATH lookup and start the copy of bash returned by same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had a custom version bash installed at ~/.new_local/bin/ that I compiled myself. Deleting that so that it defaulted to homebrew install bash fixed this issue.